# WPF Listbox: How to display selected items at the top of the list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Say for example I have 100 items in the checked ListBox starting from Item1 to Item99.  If Item20, Item30 and Item31 are selected, I would like to see the selected items on top of the list as first 3 items followed by remaining items.  Please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks
Ragu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799677/how-to-make-a-dropdownlist-show-selected-value-at-top-of-dropdown-instead-of-bot

Answer (score 0):

Since I imagine trying to select multiple items may be a bit difficult if the position is changing as you select things, I would suggest you move them when you loose focus.

An algorithm something like the following should work:

```
listbox_LostFocus()
{
    if (there are any selected items after the first unselected item)
      move them to immediately prior the first unselected item
}
```

A move can be made by calling `Items.Remove(item)` followed by `Items.Insert(item, position)`.